# How to split youtube video ID?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/R5zKIOTvfwQ?version=3"
```

and

```
 src="http://www.youtube.com/v/R5zKIOTvfwQ"
```

How can I get the video ID alone from this src?

Is there any predefined option available for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video ID is the string which is after the v/ and before the ? In your case R5zKIOTvfwQ. If you are looking for an automatic way to retrieve it, try this regex:

```
/v\/(.*)[\?$]/
```

Comment: Edit your question to give all the possible formats you may have as an input.